# What is meant by the opening and curly braces in queries in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I came across a program where in the queries are formed in a different way like this:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO projects(project_user_id, project_name, project_body) ";
$insert_query .= "VALUES({project_user_id}, '{$project_name}', '{$project_body});
```

I know the second line is meant to concatenate it with the first line in order to improve the readability of the query. But what bugs me is what is the use of the opening and closing curly braces? Is it just to improve the readability of the code or the other way around?

Comment: Looks like string interpolation (inserting variable values into the string).  With a typo on the first variable name.  And highly SQL-injectable, you should *not* do this with database queries and user-modifiable values.

Answer (score 2):

From [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex):

> **Complex (curly) syntax**
>
> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because
>   it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will
>   only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {.

Comment: Since you flagged as a possible duplicate and posted an answer, I feel this should be a community wiki instead.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner done